# How do you get Cloud9 IDE to run in the background?

Tags: bash, node.js, cloud9-ide

I have downloaded the Cloud9 IDE to my Mac according to the instructions on https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9 and everything works fine. But, I cannot seem to get it to run in the background, launching via a bash script:

Bash script called "ide" and has executable privileges:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
CLOUD_USER=`whoami`
CLOUD_DIR="/Users/$CLOUD_USER/Sites/cloud9"
CLOUD_PORT=3333
CLOUD_WORKSPACE="/Users/$CLOUD_USER/Sites"
CLOUD_ACTION="open"
CLOUD_BEFORE=""
CLOUD_AFTER=""


case "$1" in
    -b)
        CLOUD_BEFORE="nohup "
        CLOUD_AFTER="> /dev/null 2>&1 &"
        ;;
    .)
        CLOUD_WORKSPACE=`pwd`
        CLOUD_AFTER="-a $CLOUD_ACTION"
        ;;
    *)
        if [ $1 ]; then
            CLOUD_WORKSPACE=$1
        fi
        CLOUD_AFTER="-a $CLOUD_ACTION"
        ;;
esac

$CLOUD_BEFORE`/usr/local/node/bin/node $CLOUD_DIR/bin/cloud9.js -p $CLOUD_PORT -w $CLOUD_WORKSPACE` $CLOUD_AFTER
```

The idea is that you can launch this several ways:

```
$ ide
```

Will start Cloud9 and launch using the ~/Sites folder as the workspace. Or you can specify the workspace by running:

```
$ ide /path/to/workspace
```

or run the server in the background:

```
$ ide -b
```

**... which doesn't exit the script.**

I've tried downloading "forever" (https://github.com/indexzero/forever). But, when I run it in forever it takes over stdio and won't return to the command prompt.

If I run the following in the command line it runs in the background and exists correctly:

```
$ nohup /usr/local/node/bin/node /Users/{user}/Sites/cloud9/bin/cloud9.js -p 3333 -w /Users/{user}/Sites > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But, not when I run the script itself.

Any ideas about how I can force this to run in the background?

Comment: Open multiple terminals! Just leave it open in one of them.

Comment: @Raynos second question, how do you get it to _actually_ hook port 80?

Comment: @drachenstern `$ node bin/cloud9.js -h` is help.

Comment: @drachenstern $node bin/cloud9.js -p 80

Comment: @ejangi edit your question more thoroughly to reflect your bash script problem.

Comment: is that backticks around the command between before and after? That should be single or double quotes I think.

Comment: @ejangi I did that actually, sudo even, didn't quite work. I think it is the way my host is configured, working on that one tonight, try again tomorrow

Comment: @drachenstern Make sure nothing else is running on port 80. If you have apache or similar running you might have more luck proxying like so: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/using-apache-virtual-hosts-and-proxypass-together/

Comment: @ejangi I think my problem was rather _with_ the proxy I had in between, working with my host, as I said, so I will try again tomorrow. When we get free hosting, we should be willing to put up with quite a bit, yes?

Answer (score 2):

change line

```
$CLOUD_BEFORE`/usr/local/node/bin/node $CLOUD_DIR/bin/cloud9.js -p $CLOUD_PORT -w $CLOUD_WORKSPACE` $CLOUD_AFTER
```

to

```
$CLOUD_BEFORE"/usr/local/node/bin/node $CLOUD_DIR/bin/cloud9.js -p $CLOUD_PORT -w $CLOUD_WORKSPACE "$CLOUD_AFTER
```

i'm test on the following example:

```
[kaero@54221-2 ~]$ SF="sudo "
[kaero@54221-2 ~]$ FS=" aux"
[kaero@54221-2 ~]$ $SF`ps`$FS
Password:
sudo: PID: command not found
[kaero@54221-2 ~]$ $SF"ps"$FS
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
...
```

Comment: Yeah, if I run the command in the terminal directly it works fine. But, it doesn't work from inside my script for some reason.